# SQL Inner Join using selections instead of table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I'm trying to perform an Inner join on tables tab1 and tab2 have different lengths but have common data in tab1_col2 and tab2_col2 (alias_2/alias_4)

```
select
    tab1_col1 as alias_1,
    tab1_col2 as alias_2,
from db.schema.tab1
inner join (
    select
        tab2_col1 as alias_3,
        tab2_col2 as alias_4,
        tab2_colx as alias_x
    from db.schema.tab2
) on db.schema.tab1.alias_2 = db.schema.tab2.alias_4
```

I keep on getting the error there is an entry for "tab2" but it can't be referenced in this part of the query.

Comment: Like Dale K said - the main problem is that you need to alias "tab1" (e.g. alias "a") and your "select" subquery (e.g. alias "b").  Then use the aliases in your "on" clause (e.g. `on a.tab1_col2 = b.tab2_col2`).

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use 3 part naming its [not best practice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201855/mandatory-to-use-three-parts-name-in-t-sql-statements-of-sp).
2. You can't reference a column alias in the same scope its declared (except for in the `order by` clause) so you can't access `alias_2` in your join condition. You have to use the actual column name.
3. You can't access table names within a sub-query/derived-table from outside that context, so you **must** alias it and use that alias.
4. Best practice is give all you tables/derived-tables short but meaningful aliases - it makes the query much clearer.

```
select
    tab1_col1 as alias_1,
    tab1_col2 as alias_2,
from [schema].tab1 as T1
inner join (
    select
        tab2_col1 as alias_3,
        tab2_col2 as alias_4,
        tab2_colx as alias_x
    from [schema].tab2
) as T2 on T2.alias_4 = T1.tab1_col2;
```